# fiber bundles with both base and fiber as $S^1$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

What are all fiber bundles with both base and fiber as $S^1$ ? I know torus and Klein bottle. I think there are only two of them. But I dont know how to prove. How to classify them ? I am searching for some easy argument to prove such.

Comment: It is true that these are the only two types, and a more general result is proven [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/steen4.pdf) in section $6$.

Comment: Use clutching function ( see Hatcher's note for definition)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative answer without foliations : for any fiber bundle $f : E \to B$ with fiber $F$ we have $\chi(E) = \chi(F) \chi(B)$.  In your particular, $\chi(E) = 0$ so $E$ can only be the Klein bottle or the torus by the classification of compact surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Such a bundle is a 2-dimensional closed manifold with a 1-dimensional
 foliation which is a codimension 1 here. A theorem of Thurston implies that the euler characteristic of such a manifold is zero. So it is the torus or the Klein bottle.

http://www.jstor.org/stable/1971047?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: I dont have any idea about foliation. Is there any easy argument to prove such ? Is it true that if base and fiber is manifold then total space will be also a manifold?

Comment: here the foliation is just the fibers of the fibration.